# Forwarding arguments to the right nested functions in python

Tags: python, dask, args

The dask `apply_along_axis` function has the following signature:

```py
dask.array.apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr, *args, dtype=None, shape=None, **kwargs)
```

In my case, `func1d` has the following signature:

```py
my_fun(arr, x, xp, propagate=True)
```

I need to specify dtype and shape arguments (their default to `None` does not fit my case). I'm not familiar with *args and **kwargs syntaxes (I come from C++ with template parameter packs syntaxes), and even if I've tried a number call forms, I always get something along `my_fun() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shape'`.

How do I call this function to pass the right arguments to the right functions?

Repoducible example:

```py
import dask
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

def my_fun(data, x, xp):
    return data

new_array = np.zeros((100,100,100))
big_array=da.from_array(new_array, chunks=(100,100,100))
x="foo"
xp="fee"
interpolated = da.apply_along_axis(func1d=my_fun, axis=0, arr=big_array, shape=big_array.shape, dtype=big_array.dtype, x=x, xp=xp).compute()
```

Returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parallelDask.py", line 28, in <module>
    interpolated = da.apply_along_axis(func1d=my_fun, axis=0, arr=big_array, shape=big_array.shape, dtype=big_array.dtype, x=x, xp=xp).compute()
  File "/home/becheler/dev/virtual_environments/crumbs-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/array/routines.py", line 304, in apply_along_axis
    test_result = np.array(func1d(test_data, *args, **kwargs))
TypeError: my_fun() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shape'
```

EDIT: I think it comes pretty close to [this issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/3742) but I could not figure out how to solve the problem.

Comment: is `my_fun` actually `masked_interpolation`? can you show us the full [traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) and ideally create a [mre] so we can fully understand/debug the issue? at minimum it would be really helpful if you could provide one of the calls that produced the error. thanks!

Comment: So I think I solved it (not sure!). The signature of the `my_fun` functor has to end with `(*args, **kwargs)`, so the test in `apply_along_axis` can pass to it the `shape` and `dtype` without complaining (even if they are not used in the body of `my_fun`). If what I say holds, then it's quite a weird behavior I would never have expected. I guess it works for most of the use cases because usual functions like np.sum define args and kwargs in their signature. May be worth to add to the doc for those who want to write new functors?

Comment: @ArnaudBecheler The example in your question is working fine for me, without errors. :/ Could you please share your dask and numpy versions?

Comment: Interesting... My packages are dask 0.17.5, numpy 1.21.4

Comment: Omg, my dask version is 4 years old. I installed it last week, I would not have thought. I will upgrade that!

Comment: Ok, so after upgrading dask to v.2022.3.0, it works fine. I had to install it with `python -m pip install ".[complete]"`. Any idea why the previous install command I used (`pip install dask` installed such an old version? Also - thank you so much

Comment: Ok, I got it: I installed dask-rasterio in between, and that is what downgraded the dask version to 0.17!

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out! :)

Comment: I'm glad YOU figured it out :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the Dask version fixes this issue. We've verified this works with Dask `2022.3.0` -- latest Dask version at the time of answering. :)